# Display labels in Highcharts 3D scatter plot

Tags: highcharts, scatter-plot

I use Highcharts to visualize 3D charts in my project. Particularly I am interested in showing a 3D scatter plot like [this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/3d-scatter-draggable). Below the chart you can see the options as well as the respective jsFiddle.

Is there a possibility to display a label with every point's name always i.e. that hovering is not required?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the series you can enable the [datalabels](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cscatter%3E.dataLabels.enabled) like this:

```
series: [{
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
    },
}]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oghokm8w/1/

then you could use the formatter to customise the text to be displayed:

```
 series: [{
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function () {
            return this.point.x;
        },
    }
}]
```

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot!